# Haskell Simple XML generation gives compile error

Tags: haskell, xml-generation

I am trying to learn to use the [xmlgen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmlgen-0.4.0.3) library, but when I tried the example from http://factisresearch.blogspot.in/2011/05/xmlgen-feature-rich-and-high.html I get a compile error.

Here is the code:

```
import Text.XML.Generator
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import Prelude as P

genXml' :: Xml Doc
genXml' =
  let people = [("Stefan", "32"), ("Judith", "4")]
  in doc defaultDocInfo $
       xelem "people" $
         xelems $ P.map (\(name, age) -> xelem "person" (xattr "age" age <#> xtext name)) people

outputXml :: IO ()
outputXml = BSL.putStr (xrender genXml')
```

The compiler errors:

```
$ ghc --make prog.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prog.hs, prog.o )

prog.hs:13:25:
    No instance for (XmlOutput ByteString)
      arising from a use of `xrender'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (XmlOutput ByteString)
    In the first argument of `BSL.putStr', namely `(xrender genXml')'
    In the expression: BSL.putStr (xrender genXml')
    In an equation for `outputXml':
        outputXml = BSL.putStr (xrender genXml')
```

The compiler seems to be deducing that "xrender genXML'" needs to be of type "XmlOutput ByteString" and there is an instance of this in the xmlgen library. So please help me with understanding what this error means, and how it can be fixed.

If it helps, I am using the Haskell Platform in Ubuntu 12.10, ghc 7.4.2 and the xmlgen 0.4.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The compiler seems to be deducing that "xrender genXML'" needs to be of type "XmlOutput ByteString"

No, the compiler deduces (from the use of `BSL.putStr`) that `xrender genXML'` needs to be of type `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString`.

Since the type of `xrender` is

```
xrender :: (Renderable r, XmlOutput t) => Xml r -> t
```

a necessary condition to be able to instantiate `t` with `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString` is an `XmlOutput` instance for lazy `ByteString`s.

Since there is such an instance exported from `Text.XML.Generator`, the only cause for the error message that I see is that your

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
```

imports the module from a different version of the [`bytestring`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) package than the `xmlgen` library was built against.

Can you check that with `ghc-pkg describe xmlgen`, which lists the `bytestring` version it was built against among the dependencies, and `ghc-pkg list bytestring` to check which `bytestring` versions you have installed?

Comment: Thank you for the response. My xmlgen was built against bytestring-0.9.2.1, and I have two versions of bytestring installed: bytestring-0.9.2.1 and bytestring-0.10.0.1. If this was a proper project, I suppose I would specify the version in a .cabal file, but just for learning purposes, how can I tell the compiler to use a particular version of bytestring while compiling this file?

Comment: So without specification of the version of `bytestring` to use, the compiler uses the newest. To tell it which version to use, `ghc -package bytestring-0.9.2.1 prog`. With ghc >= 7, you don't need the `--make` anymore.